# how to automatically join a bunch of sas datasets

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to functionise some of my SAS operations

I have a bunch of tables which all have the same index (id) and the same number of rows

Each time I call the function that I want to write, the number of tables can differ. I intend to store the names of the tables in a dataset to loop over them.
Sometimes there will only be 3 tables, but sometimes there could be hundreds

How do I write an automatic join to all the tables, but only keep one column of the "ID" - the ID exists in all tables so I would like to drop them all apart from the first table I join

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to a macro here. If you post your macro, we can make suggestions but as your question is phrased there are too many possible answers. If you're using a Data Step vs PROC SQL the answers will differ.

Comment: ok - i realise my question is too generic. it would be proc sql rather than data step

Comment: My next question - are you sure you need a join rather than an append. Long data is easier to automate than wide data. And you can always transpose it afterwards if required.

Comment: how would you append - if i set all of them together they would stack together but they all have different columns

Comment: If the columns are different then probably not :(

Comment: Are you assuming that you're going to bring in all columns other than ID from each table?

Comment: if the id column contains a unique set of id's i.e. no ids are repeated in a given table and if the columns other then id do not overlap between tables then this is pretty easy to do.  Tell us more about the data

Comment: @DCR the tables are all the same number of rows, have the same id (named the same) but each has different numbers of columns. very simple datasets. I may end up with over 100 datasets though, and won't always be joining all of them

Answer (score 0):

If you want PROC SQL to figure out the key variable(s) for you then use the `NATURAL JOIN` operation.  If some id's will appear in some datasets and not others then use `NATURAL FULL JOIN`.

```
data a (keep=id a1 a2) b(keep=id b1 b2) c(keep=id c1 c2) ;
  input id a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2 ;
  if id ne 1 then output a;
  if id ne 2 then output b;
  if id ne 3 then output c;
cards;
1 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 7 8 9 10 11 12
3 13 14 15 16 17 18 
;;;;
proc sql noprint ;
  create table want as
  select * from c natural full join 
   (select * from b natural full join a)
  ;
quit;
```

Which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you're looking.  Look it over and if you have any questions post back:

```
 data test.table1;                                                                                                                      
 ID = 1;                                                                                                                                
 A=7;                                                                                                                                   
 B=8;                                                                                                                                   
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 ID = 2;                                                                                                                                
 A=9;                                                                                                                                   
 B=10;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 ID = 3;                                                                                                                                
 A=11;                                                                                                                                  
 B=12;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 RUN;                                                                                                                                   


 data test.table2;                                                                                                                      
 ID = 1;                                                                                                                                
 C=9;                                                                                                                                   
 D=10;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 ID = 2;                                                                                                                                
 C=11;                                                                                                                                  
 D=12;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 ID = 3;                                                                                                                                
 C=13;                                                                                                                                  
 D=14;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 RUN;                                                                                                                                   


 data test.table3;                                                                                                                      
 ID = 1;                                                                                                                                
 E=11;                                                                                                                                  
 F=12;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 ID = 2;                                                                                                                                
 E=13;                                                                                                                                  
 F=14;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 ID = 3;                                                                                                                                
 E=15;                                                                                                                                  
 F=16;                                                                                                                                  
 OUTPUT;                                                                                                                                
 RUN;                                                                                                                                   


proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                       
    create table test.names_tables as                                                                                                   
    select distinct libname,memname                                                                                                     
    from sashelp.vcolumn                                                                                                                
    where libname = "TEST"                                                                                                              
    and substr(memname,1,5)="TABLE";                                                                                                    
quit;                                                                                                                                   

proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                       
    select count(*) into: cnt                                                                                                           
    from test.names_tables;                                                                                                             
quit;                                                                                                                                   

%let cnt = &cnt;                                                                                                                        

%macro jmac;                                                                                                                            


proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                       
     select libname,memname into: lib, :table                                                                                           
     from test.names_tables                                                                                                             
     where monotonic() = 1;                                                                                                             
quit;                                                                                                                                   

%let lib = &lib;                                                                                                                        
%let table = &table;                                                                                                                    

%let fname = &lib..&table;                                                                                                              

data test.tablejoin;                                                                                                                    
set &fname;                                                                                                                             
run;                                                                                                                                    

%let fname = test.tablejoin;                                                                                                            

%do i=2 %to &cnt;                                                                                                                       
proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                       
     select libname,memname into: lib1, :table1                                                                                         
     from test.names_tables                                                                                                             
     where monotonic() = &i;                                                                                                            
quit;                                                                                                                                   

%let fname1 = &lib1..&table1;                                                                                                           


proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                       
     create table &fname as                                                                                                             
     select a.*,b.*                                                                                                                     
     from &fname as a                                                                                                                   
     full join                                                                                                                          
          &fname1 as b                                                                                                                  
     on a.id = b.id;                                                                                                                    
quit;                                                                                                                                   


%end;                                                                                                                                   

%mend jmac;                                                                                                                             
%jmac;
```